# How to get Loopback 3 conditional 'datasources' and 'model-config': following instructions and doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, environment-variables, amazon-dynamodb, loopbackjs

Edit: I was able to get it to work partway, if I assumed that the 'local' variants could only *overwrite* already defined structures.  That is, I need to define the data sources 'DynamoDB' and 'mongo' in `datasources.json` and override them in `datasources.local.js`.  This, however, isn't what we want to do -- when we deploy to AWS, we don't want to have MongoDB involved in any way.  Any help much appreciated!

---

We need to configure Loopback data sources and model configurations depending on a node `env` variable. Specifically, we need to switch between MongoDB as our DB for local development, and DynamoDB when it's deployed.   I followed the instructions [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Environment-specific-configuration.html), which say
[image]

Apparently, according to [this post](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-boot/issues/101), I think one has to have the 'regular'  `datasources.json` and `model-config.json`, and the other files can only *add* to what is defined there.

In any case, I added `datasources.local.js` and `model-config.local.js` but I still get the error.  The environment variable `LOOPBACK_ENV` is being set correctly (to 'mongo' in this case) in the `.env` file

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Event is referencing a dataSource that does not exist: "mongo"
    at configureModel (/Users/abc/Documents/projects/abc-adj-new/node_modules/loopback/lib/application.js:584:5)
    at Function.app.model (/Users/abc/Documents/projects/abc-adj-new/node_modules/loopback/lib/application.js:126:5)
    at /Users/abc/Documents/projects/abc-adj-new/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:203:9
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at setupModels (/Users/abc/Documents/projects/chatbot-adj-new/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:199:23)
    at execute (/Users/abc/Documents/projects/abc-adj-new/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:40:3)
    at bootLoopBackApp (/Users/abc/Documents/projects/abc-adj-new/node_modules/loopback-boot/index.js:154:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/abc/Documents/projects/abc-adj-new/server/server.js:79:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  generatedMessage: false,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: false,
  expected: true,
  operator: '=='
}
```

I will add the files below.  This is Loopback 3, Node 12.13.  Any help much appreciated!

```
// server/datasources.json
{
    "db": {
        "name": "db",
        "connector": "memory"
    },


    "emailDataSource": {
        "name": "emailDataSource",
        "connector": "mail",
        "transports": [
            {
                "type": "smtp",
                "host": "smtp-service",
                "secure": false,
                "port": 25,
                "tls": {
                    "rejectUnauthorized": false
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

---

```
  //  server/datasources.local.js
   if (process.env.LOOPBACK_ENV === "mongo") {
  module.exports = {

    "dynamodb": {
      "name": "dynamodb",
      "connector": "dynamodb",
      "region": "ap-northeast-1",
      "credentials": "shared",
      "profile": "iamrole"
    }

  };
} else {
  module.exports = {

    "mongo": {
      "url": "${MONGO_URL}",
      "name": "mongo",
      "connector": "mongodb",
      "allowExtendedOperators": true,
      "useNewUrlParser": true
    }
  };
}
```

---

```
//  server/model-config.json
{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "loopback/common/models",
      "loopback/server/models",
      "../common/models",
      "./models",
      "../node_modules/bot-analytics/models"
    ],
    "mixins": [
      "loopback/common/mixins",
      "loopback/server/mixins",
      "../common/mixins",
      "./mixins",
      "../node_modules/amf-lb-expose-remote-methods-mixin/lib"
    ]
  },
  "Variable": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  }

}
```

---

```
// server/model-config.js
if (process.env.LOOPBACK_ENV === "mongo") {
  module.exports ={

    "Event": {
      "dataSource": "mongo",
      "public": true
    },
    "History": {
      "dataSource": "mongo",
      "public": true
    },
    "Email": {
      "dataSource": "mongo"
    },
    "FileUpload": {
      "dataSource": "mongo",
      "public": true
    } ,
    "ADJUser" : {
      "dataSource": "mongo"
    }
  }

} else {
  module.exports = {

    "Event": {
      "dataSource": "dynamodb",
      "public": true
    },
    "History": {
      "dataSource": "dynamodb",
      "public": true
    },
    "Email": {
      "dataSource": "dynamodb"
    },
    "FileUpload": {
      "dataSource": "dynamodb",
      "public": true
    } ,
    "ADJUser" : {
      "dataSource": "dynamodb"
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure I will make a proper answer to your question - but here's what I usually do in my projects:

I have many files in the `server` folder depending on the configuration which serve different purposes depending on the configuration loaded. Usually like:

```
/server/middleware.json (for localhost)
/server/middleware.staging.json
/server/middleware.production.json

/server/datasources.json (for localhost)
/server/datasources.staging.json
/server/datasources.production.json
```

... and so on for each environments and files.

Then, depending on the environment, I launch the app with a specific command:

```
NODE_ENV=production npm start server/server.js
```

The `NODE_ENV` attribute will tell the app which configuration file to read. If you don't provide any, the first files will be read (in my example `/server/middleware.json` and `/server/datasources.json`)

Hope this helps!